# Pandas Dataframe to the dict of list with tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, type-conversion, dataframe

I have some data in the Dataframe (say, `df`):

```
Col_1   Col_2   Col_3
Key1    ACURA   CL
Key2    ACURA   EL
Key2    ACURA   ILX
Key3    ACURA   INTEGRA
Key4    ACURA   INTEGRA
```

The way I want to see it:

```
{'key1': [('ACURA', 'CL')], 
 'key2': [('ACURA', 'EL'), ('ACURA', 'ILX')], 
 'key3': [('ACURA', 'INTEGRA')], 
 'key4': [('ACURA', 'INTEGRA')]}
```

I tried something like `df.set_index('Col_1').T.to_dict('list')` but failed as Col_1 had non-unique values.
There is, of course, a simple solution to run through the df row-by-row and create my dict manually, but I prefer more Pythonic way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does what you want:

```
In [50]:
df.groupby('Col_1')[['Col_2','Col_3']].apply(lambda x: [tuple(x) for x in x.values]).to_dict()

Out[50]:
{'Key1': [('ACURA', 'CL')],
 'Key2': [('ACURA', 'EL'), ('ACURA', 'ILX')],
 'Key3': [('ACURA', 'INTEGRA')],
 'Key4': [('ACURA', 'INTEGRA')]}
```

Here we `groupby` on 'Col_1', we then turn the values into a tuple inside a list and on the result call `to_dict`

Comment: No, it does not provide me with the desired outcome. Look the format I want for the 'key2': 'key2': [('ACURA', 'EL'), ('ACURA', 'ILX')]. Note, there are two instances with 'key2'.

Comment: updated now, it can probably be cleaned up looking at it

Comment: The .apply() throws this error for me: "TypeError: Series.name must be a hashable type"